# Scifi series with main character building his own ship from secret engine, set in galactic empire

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find the name of a scifi series, but can only remember scattered parts of it!  It starts with the protagonist on a planet (possibly all alone) and he has no memory of the past. He builds his own spaceship using the parts of a crashed military ship, including the secret "black box" power-source/engine.  His ship is able to go faster than any others.

A bit later he races his space ship in a huge race, possibly on Earth, definitely in the solar system, wins, and meets the immortal emperor and family.

His space ship is different from all modern ships, and I think looked like a current jet.  The military is broken up into different forces with a lot of competition between them.

That's about all I can remember I  think.  I suspect the books were from the 70's or 80's, although not certain; I read it in the late 90's/early 00's.  Help!!

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Take a few moments to see if [there's any details you can add to help us identify this story](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)